# If I have a GPU server with 1PFlop/s single-precision floating-point power, can I do double-precision calculations?

Tags: hpc

If I have a GPU server with 1PFlop/s single-precision floating-point power, can I do double-precision calculations? If so, how much computing power is equivalent to double precision calculation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the GPU model that is available: typically high-end GPUs like the Nvidia A100 have a fairly good amount of double precision units that can accelerate suitable applications.

The other main factor is the "suitable application": the amount of Flop/s you can extract from your GPU server changes depending on the nature of your application and the specific implementation.